# Angular Directive template to array in a controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive, angular-controller

Here is the directive

```
directives.directive("unitDirective", function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: "../html/directives/unitDir.html"
  }
});
```

Here is the template

```
<div ng-repeat="unit in addUnit()">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Unit {{unit+1}}</span>
    <input type="number" placeholder="enter estimated monthly rent" ng-model="units.price[$index]">
  </label>
  </div>
```

Here is where I would like the button to be

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>

    <unit-directive></unit-directive>
    <button class="button buttomn-assertive">Confirm</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is my controller:

```
controllers.controller("unitsCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams){

    $scope.units = {
        price: [1,2]
    }
    $scope.addUnit = function(){
      var dummyArray = [];
      for(var i =0; i < $stateParams.units; i++){
        dummyArray[i] = i;
      }
      return dummyArray;
    };

    $scope.calculate= function(){

      //how do I access the array of units prices here?
    }

  });
```

Basically, i used cordovadialog plugin to ask how many units they want to create and then i made a dummy array with the number provided and used it for ng-repeat. Now, I have to take in all the inputs and store them in an array and I am stuck.
Any general direction to any other possible duplicate question, a solution or documentation/tutorial would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it!! Instead of directives being a completely different module, I changed the directive to be a directive of controller module where I was trying to access the value.